# Pyrogram raw functions.channels.GetFullChannel not working

Tags: pyrogram

For example, i wrote a simple echo-bot, but GetFullChannel is not working.

```
from pyrogram import Client, filters, enums
from pyrogram.raw import functions, types

app = Client(username, api_id, api_hash)

@app.on_message(filters.text)
async def echo(client, message):
    if message.text == "test":
        r = await app.invoke(functions.channels.GetFullChannel(channel=-100********21))
        print(r)
```

My code failed and return this trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/******/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyrogram/dispatcher.py", line 240, in handler_worker
    await handler.callback(self.client, *args)
  File "**************.py", line 84, in echo
    ret = await app.invoke(functions.channels.GetFullChannel(channel=-100********21))
  File "/home/*****/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyrogram/methods/advanced/invoke.py", line 77, in invoke
    r = await self.session.invoke(
  File "/home/*****/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyrogram/session/session.py", line 361, in invoke
    return await self.send(query, timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/******/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyrogram/session/session.py", line 290, in send
    message = self.msg_factory(data)
  File "/home/*****/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyrogram/session/internals/msg_factory.py", line 37, in __call__
    len(body)
  File "/home/*****/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyrogram/raw/core/tl_object.py", line 79, in __len__
    return len(self.write())
  File "/home/******/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyrogram/raw/functions/channels/get_full_channel.py", line 69, in write
    b.write(self.channel.write())
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'write'
```

The author of the Pyrogram framework says that there is no error in the libraries themselves, it is in my implementation.

Can you tell me what is wrong in my code?
Am I using the raw function incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should give `InputChannel` not peer id of it

Test :

```
channel = await app.resolve_peer(-100********21)
r = await app.invoke(functions.channels.GetFullChannel(channel=channel ))
```