# How can I get the channel name with its channel_id using the pyrogram library?

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

How can I get the channel name with its channel_id using the pyrogram library?

```py
import time
from pyrogram import Client
from pyrogram import types, filters
from loguru import logger
import config


app = Client(
    "asyncBot",
    api_id=config.api_id,
    api_hash=config.api_hash
)

clicks = 0

@app.on_message()
async def my_handler(client: Client, message: types.Message):

cchat = client.get_chat.title(config.CHANNEL_ID)
print(cchat)

app.run()
```

But this method doesn't work, I don't quite understand how to work with the title method in pyrogram, please advise!

Comment: please provide context to the question....  the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I need to get the name of the channel by its ID, updated data question

Comment: it appears as though you have missed the indentation on the `async def my_handler()` method...

Comment: No, its okey. I not undestend using method title() on pyrogram, please help on this question

Comment: you have missed the indentation and have also need to await the `client.get`.   please provide a working minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pyrogram raw functions.channels.GetFullChannel not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74082156/pyrogram-raw-functions-channels-getfullchannel-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

```python
import time
from pyrogram import Client
from pyrogram import types, filters
from loguru import logger
import config


app = Client(
    "asyncBot",
    api_id=config.api_id,
    api_hash=config.api_hash
)

clicks = 0

@app.on_message(filters.me)
async def my_handler(client: Client, message: Message):
    # If chat is Channel/Group/SuperGroup
    title = message.chat.title

    # If chat is Private (between users)
    first_name = message.chat.first_name
    last_name = message.chat.last_name

    # So you can get the chat name anyway
    title_list = [message.chat.first_name, message.chat.last_name, message.chat.title]
    full_title = ' '.join(filter(None, title_list))

    # Sending data to the same chat where the message came from
    await message.reply_text(full_title)


# Proper use of get_chat
async def get_chat_title(chat_id: Union[int, str]):
    async with app:
        chat = await app.get_chat(chat_id)

        # Next chat.title, chat.first_name and chat.last_name
        # depending on the type of chat

        # return what you need


# For run get_chat_title
# app.run(get_chat_title(123123123))

# For listen message incoming client (for work message handlers)
app.run()
```

I hope you have already found solutions